# Python CSV: selecting only specific column headers

Tags: python, csv

Regarding the csv module in Python:

Example - the content of the first file:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv, header1, header2
file3.csv, file4.csv, header1, header2, header5
file5.csv, file6.csv, header2
```

I read the first file (file1.csv) and need to only export the columns with header1 and header2.

For the next file (file3.csv), I need to only export header1, header2 and header5 to file4.csv.

I have an array (myParameters = row["targetcolumns"] with all the header names in it, and I need to loop that somehow while creating rows, writing it to the file, and continue with the next line.

I have no idea how to do that.

Problem is that sometimes I need 4 headers, the next time only one, ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dictionary with {header:value} for each row then you can simply:

```
for row in rows:
    csv.writerow([row[h] for h in myParameters])
```

Then for each file myParameters will be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
f = open("somefile.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    l = line.split()
    f1= l[0]
    f2 = l[1]
    headers = l[2:]
    file2 = open(f2, "r")
    for h in headers:
        file2.write(','.join(headers) + '\n')
    with open(f1, "r") as filename:
        r = csv.DictReader(filename)
        for x in r:
            out = []
            for h in headers:
                out.append(x[h])
            file2.write(','.join(out) + '\n')
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use a csvwriter, to ensure correctly formatted output, delimiter, quoting, etc.?